# Tooltip text-alignment with Jquery ui

Tags: css, jquery-ui, text, tooltip, text-alignment

Jquery tooltip text is aligned to the center. I need to align it to the left.
This is my example.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
    });
```

`</script>`
   `</head>`
    `<body>`
    `<p><input class="age" title="how to align left?.how to align left?.how to align left?.how to align left?.how to align left?.how to align left?.how to align left?.how to align left?.how to align left?."></p>`

   `</body>`
    `</html>`

I look through `jquery` js and `css` files and could not find, where I can edit `text alignment` for `tooltip`.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

So there is no **configuration option**, which would give you control over alignment of the content of `ui-tooltip`, so you need to resort to setting things up, with `CSS`.

In accordance of [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/), in section **Theming**:

> *The tooltip widget uses the jQuery UI CSS framework to style its look
>   and feel. If tooltip specific styling is needed, the following CSS
>   class names can be used:*
>
> - *`ui-tooltip`: The outer container for the tooltip*.
> - *`ui-tooltip-content`: The content of the tooltip.*

So in your case, you could either use:

```
.ui-tooltip {
  text-align:left;
}
```

or:

```
.ui-tooltip-content {
  text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: I found the problem source. In my main CSS file I had setting:                             div { text-align:center; }                                                                                                                          When I change it to text-align:left;     I fixed alignment                                                                                                    Thank you anyway..